# $\sigma=(12345)(67)(89)$, is $\sigma^{2002}$ conjugated with $\sigma^4$?

Tags: group-theory

$\sigma=(12345)(67)(89)$, is $\sigma^{2002}$ conjugated with $\sigma^4$ in $S_9$?

I have $\sigma^{2002}=(13524)(67)(89)$ and $\sigma^4=\sigma^{-1}=(54321)(67)(89)$

Hence, they have same cykeltype and are therefore conjugated, is this correct answer?

Comment: In any even power of $\sigma$ the transpositions should reduce to identity on the elements they transpose. Check your computation.

Comment: The final conclusion is correct but the calculations are not quite right: $\sigma$ has order $10$ (not $5$ as you suggested with $\sigma^4=\sigma^{-1}$), so $\sigma^{2002}=\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As disjoint permutations commute, we have  $$\sigma^{2002}=(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)^{2002\bmod 5}(6\,7)^{2002\bmod 2}(8\,9)^{2002\bmod 2}=(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)^{2}=(1\,3\,5\,2\,4)$$
whereas
$$\sigma^4=(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)^{4}=(1\,2\,3\,4\,5)^{-1}=(1\,5\,4\,3\,2),$$
and it is easy to check that
$$(2\,4)(3\,5)\sigma^4(2\,4)(3\,5)=\sigma^2.$$

Comment: The last check isn't even necessary as long as you know the useful fact that two permutations are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle type.  In this case, both things consist of a single 5-cycle.

Comment: @Aaron: I supposed the O.P. is a beginner, and was not sure whether he knows this fact.